# Futures for Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, concurrency

Has anyone implemented [Futures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_(programming)) in Objective-C? I (hopefully not naively) assume that it should be reasonably simple to wrap NSInvocations in a nice API?

Comment: http://mobisoftinfotech.com//tutorials/essential-swift/essential-swift-for-objective-c-programmers.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mike Ash has implemented Futures using Blocks:

- http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-02-26-futures.html
- http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-03-05-compound-futures.html

Answer (score 8):

**[PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit)** seems quite popular. There's my **[Collapsing Futures](https://github.com/Strilanc/ObjC-CollapsingFutures)** library. There's also **[RXPromise](https://github.com/couchdeveloper/RXPromise)**. And plenty more.

Some notes between those three:

- PromiseKit has Swift support
- Each can be installed via CocoaPods.
- Each automatically flattens doubly-future values into singly-future values.
- Each is thread-safe.
- RXPromise and PromiseKit act like Promises/A+ from JavaScript.
- They differ in how futures are controlled. In collapsing futures there's a FutureSource, which has-a future instead of is-a future. In RXPromise and PromiseKit, a future is its own source.
- They differ in how future are cancelled. In RXPromise the consumer calls `cancel` on the future itself. In collapsing futures, the producer [cancels a token](http://twistedoakstudios.com/blog/Post7391_cancellation-tokens-and-collapsing-futures-for-objective-c) it gave to the method that made the future. I don't know what PromiseKit does.
- All have excellent documentation on each method.

I'm biased towards collapsing futures, since I wrote it and so clearly prefer the design decisions it made. I think keeping control separate is hugely important because it helps prevent self-sustaining reference cycles (not an issue in JS, but definitely an issue in Obj-C when working with blocks). I also think cancel tokens simply make things easier. On the other hand, acting like a well-known spec from a well-known language would be really nice.

Comment: _Cancellation_ is an exceedingly important feature of a Future implementation, even though the "Promises/A+ Spec" does not suggest it in its core API. "Collapsing Futures" has a well designed means to accomplish cancellation, as well as RXPromise -it's just not that "explicit": sending `cancel` to a promise first off means, that the sender abandons its interest in the future. If this is the root promise, the underlying task *may* forward this cancel event by simply registering a handler and then cancel itself. There are also means that a task will be cancelled when there are no more consumers.

Answer (score 3):

[MPWFoundation](http://github.com/mpw/MPWFoundation) has futures based on [Higher Order Messaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_order_message):

Assuming you have a regular computation with a message `computeResult`:

```
result = [someObject computeResult];
```

prefixing that message with the `future` message will compute the result in the background:

```
result = [[someObject future] computeResult];
```

The object in `result` is a proxy that will block when messages are sent to it until the value is received.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's documentation on [blocks in Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/BlocksGCD/_index.html) may be of interest.

Comment: link is broken.