# Smalltalk blocks in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, lambda, closures, smalltalk, objective-c-blocks

Does Objective-C support blocks "a la Smalltalk"?

In Smalltalk, blocks are similar to "closures" or "lambda-expressions" or "nameless functions" found in other languages.

Comment: See this question for some additional links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516325/futures-for-objective-c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Out of the box, they're only supported in the version of Objective-C 2.0 that comes with XCode 3.2 or later. This means you'll need Snow Leopard if you want to use the official build tools. A potential work-around for 10.5 is described here: http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/#leoiphone

Comment: But there are distinct in one aspect: the way you return from it.

Comment: (Just a note) Corresponding version of iOS also support C-Blocks feature.

Answer (score 6):

Yep,
take this example:

```
[[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *line = (NSString *)obj;
    //do what your going to do with line...
}];
```

Comment: Am I interpreting this code correctly? Can ObjC handle arbitrarily typed blocks, or only explicitly typed blocks?

Comment: @mcandre objective-c is not a strongly-typed language. You can pass an `id` or `void *` and cast it to whatever type you want.